# Dimensionality reduction being way too slow using PCA and a small dataset

Tags: python, numpy, pca

I have the following data set stored using numpy:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ppseiv9skqlhljr/AACQEWZh11oszL5-Z_NHqre3a?dl=0

There is a different numpy file for the training and development partitions of the data set

```
[50,1,396]
```

I am using PCA Fast from the mlpy library in order to perform dimensionality reduction. However the whole process is too slow and I can not find out why.
Before I perform the PCA I convert the dataset to the following shape:

```
[50,396]
```

So the shape of the dataset is not the cause of my problem.

The code I use is the following:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import sys
import csv
import mlpy

inputfiletrain=''
outputfiletrain=''
inputfiledev=''
outputfiledev=''

def parseCommandLineArgs():
        global inputfiletrain
        global outputfiletrain
        global inputfiledev
        global outputfiledev

        for i in range(0, len(sys.argv)):

                if sys.argv[i] == 'inputfiletrain':
                        inputfiletrain = sys.argv[i + 1]
                        print
                        print "------*****Using Directory :*****------"
                        print 'inputfiletrain=' + inputfiletrain
                        print "------**********************------"
                        print

                if sys.argv[i] == 'outputfiletrain':
                        outputfiletrain = sys.argv[i + 1]
                        print
                        print "------*****Using Directory :*****------"
                        print 'outputfiletrain=' + outputfiletrain
                        print "------**********************------"
                        print

                if sys.argv[i] == 'inputfiledev':
                        inputfiledev = sys.argv[i + 1]
                        print
                        print "------*****Using Directory :*****------"
                        print 'inputfiledev=' + inputfiledev
                        print "------**********************------"
                        print

                if sys.argv[i] == 'outputfiledev':
                        outputfiledev = sys.argv[i + 1]
                        print
                        print "------*****Using outputFeatures Filename :*****------"
                        print 'outputfiledev=' + outputfiledev
                        print "------**********************------"
                        print




def pcaDimRed(features, nDims):
        X=np.empty([features.shape[0], features.shape[2]])
        print features.shape[2]
        print X.shape


        for i,f in enumerate(features):

            #np.append(X,f[0],axis=0)

            X[i]=f[0]
        #np.vstack(X)


        print X
        print "PCAStarting"
    #pca = mlpy.PCA(method='cov')
    pca=  mlpy.PCAFast(k=nDims, eps=0.1)
    pca.learn(X)
    coeff = pca.coeff()
    coeff = coeff[:,0:nDims]

        print "PCAEnding"
    featuresNew = []
    for f in X:
        ft = f.copy()
#       ft = pca.transform(ft, k=nDims)
        ft = np.dot(f, coeff)
        featuresNew.append(ft)


        thodwrisformat = np.empty((len(files), 1, mean.shape[0]))
        for i,f in enumerate(featuresNew):
            thodwrisformat[i][0]=f

    return (thodwrisformat, coeff)

def pcaDevelopmentSet(features, nDims,coeff):

        featuresNew = []

                for f in features:
                        ft = f.copy()
        #       ft = pca.transform(ft, k=nDims)
                        ft = np.dot(f, coeff)
                        featuresNew.append(ft)
                return featuresNew

parseCommandLineArgs()
print inputfiledev
FeaturesDev = np.load(inputfiledev)
FeaturesTrain = np.load(inputfiletrain)

PCATrain=pcaDimRed(FeaturesTrain,68)
FeaturesTrain=PCATrain[1]
coeff=PCATrain[2]
FeaturesDev=pcaDevelopmentSet(FeaturesDev, 68,coeff)


np.save(outputfiledev,FeaturesDev)
np.save(outputfiletrain,FeaturesTrain)
```

I am using this code under ubuntu linux and python 2.7. To install mlpy one has to use the following commands:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mlpy/files/mlpy%203.5.0/mlpy-3.5.0.tar.gz
tar xvf mlpy-3.5.0.tar.gz
cd mlpy-3.5.0
sudo python setup.py install
```

Finally to run this code, assuming the script is stored as pca.py and it is is in the same folder that the directory feature_vectors containing the partitions of the datasets resides, one must use the following command:

```
python pca.py inputfiletrain feature_vectors/train/featuresShape.npy outputfiletrain feature_vectors/train/featuresShapePCA.npy inputfiledev feature_vectors/development/featuresShape.npy outputfiledev feature_vectors/development/featuresShapePCA.npy
```

I need ideas, why the PCA is that slow on this dataset...

Comment: What makes you assume that this operation *should* be faster? Do you have evidence that it is faster for different, but comparable in size, datasets; or under different circumstances?

Comment: yes the fast pca example they offer in the documentation of the mlpy project produces random matrices of size (100,100) that are processed much faster... http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.2/dim_red.html

Comment: @obelix but this is a biger 50x396 matrix! 19800 vs. 10.000. And you didn't mentioned how do you measure fastness: per epochs or per batches?

Comment: per hours leaving my laptop running the algorithm... still though it should end in a more logical amount of time... i've left my laptop awake for more than 8 hours and the process had not been completed...

Comment: And the speed of example 100x100?

Comment: less than five minutes

Comment: Do you see some process indicator?

Comment: i've left it for a whole night...

Comment: OK I'm trying reproduce your issue, but the installing of mlpy is problematic somehow and currently: I get the following: 
The sourceforge.net website is temporarily in static offline mode.
Only a very limited set of project pages are available until the main website returns to service.

Comment: Yes currently sourceforge.net is down for maintenance... Try again later if possible...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your discuss:

- If you measure fastness per batches: your process will be slower because of higher dimensionality i.e. data shape of 396.
- If you measure fastness per epoch: your process will be slower because of more data i.e. 50x396 = 19800 vs. the 100x100 random example.

Comment: If i use the timer the 100x100 example dataset takes less than five minutes.... my dataset takes more than 8 hours and the process is not completed....

Comment: OK I try to reproduce it.

Comment: Are you sure that mlpy install method is correct: george@templar:~$ tar xvf mlpy-3.5.0.tar.gz

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now